How to update doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites status?
I'm coding a chat screen in Flutter and I'm using a StreamBuilder to get all my messages. I would like that while my message isn't sent to my database a circular progress indicator is displayed.
Here my chatScreen:
StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
        stream: messageProvider.getMessagesListStreamDocs(
            userProvider.userAccount!.uid, userAccount!.uid),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //Snapshot verif
          final documents = snapshot.data!;
          final messages = documents.map((doc) {
            final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return MessageModel.fromJson(data);
          }).toList();

          return Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GroupedListView<MessageModel, DateTime>(
                  elements: messages,
                itemBuilder: (context, MessageModel element) {
                    final doc = documents.firstWhere((doc) => doc.id == element.messageUid);
                    final isPending = doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites;
                    print(isPending);

                    return Column(
                      // Message Design with a Container
                                    if (isPending) //I add a circular progress indicator
                                      Padding(
                                        //I add my circular Progress Indicator
                                )

Here messageProvider.getMessagesListStreamDocs:
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getMessagesListStreamDocs(String uid, String contactUid) {
    return _firebaseStore
        .collection(collectionUser)
        .doc(uid)
        .collection(collectionChats)
        .doc(contactUid)
        .collection(collectionMessages)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
        return [];
      }

      return snapshot.docs;
    });
  }

However, even when my document has been written in my database, the circular progress indicator remains until I leave and go back to my chat or reload. I tested with a print and it seems myStreamBuilder only gets updated when I send my message (so doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites = true but no anymore (excluding if I
send a new message)). I don't know how to update it?
